# Vuejs app simple fetch post only insert the _id and not the json

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, post, fetch

I have an app with Vue.js and in a method I created a simple fetch to post to my API, but only the `_id` is saved in my mongodb.

My method in Vuejs app (i created a variable with the json to test my fetch post):

```
saveAllResults(){
            let myvalue ='{"Step2":[{"selected":!1,"produto":"A70-5","ncm":"9506.62.00","aliqII":.2,"aliqIpi":0,"aliqPis":.021,"aliqCofins":.0965,"descricao":"BOLA DE BASQUETE","pesoUnitario":.43,"unitario":.78,"dumping":0,"cubagemUnitario":0,"quantidade":150,"icmEstadoDestino":0,"mvaAjustado":0,"markup":.12},{"selected":!1,"produto":"PINK-7-103","ncm":"7117.90.00","aliqII":.18,"aliqIpi":.12,"aliqPis":.021,"aliqCofins":.0965,"descricao":"BIJOUTERIAS EM METAL/ VIDRO ","pesoUnitario":.975,"unitario":1.52,"dumping":0,"cubagemUnitario":0,"quantidade":200,"icmEstadoDestino":0,"mvaAjustado":0,"markup":.11},{"selected":!1,"produto":"PINK-7-103","ncm":"7117.90.00","aliqII":.18,"aliqIpi":.12,"aliqPis":.021,"aliqCofins":.0965,"descricao":"BIJOUTERIAS EM METAL/ VIDRO ","pesoUnitario":.975,"unitario":1.52,"dumping":0,"cubagemUnitario":0,"quantidade":300,"icmEstadoDestino":0,"mvaAjustado":0,"markup":.19}],}';
           
            fetch('http://localhost:4242/api/v1/dis', {
                method: 'post',
                body: myvalue
            }).then(function(response){
                return response.json(myvalue);
            }).then(function(text){
                console.log(text);
            }).catch(function (error){
                console.error(error);
            })
            
}
```

my route in my API (I'm using express, morgan, joi, helmet, cors, bodyParse with mongoDB)

```
// CREATE  ONE 
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const value = await schema.validateAsync(req.body);
        const inserted = await dis.insert(value);
        res.json(inserted);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

When i try to post the same json data using [Isominia](https://support.insomnia.rest/category/9-getting-started) (or postman) the post works fine, but with my fecth post request only the `_id` is generated and don't post all the data that I want.

The Fetch Post return in console:

```
{_id: "5f376d6edd37760c6632c8ab"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After totally forgot that you need to specify the `headers` in your  `fetch POST request` to pass the json to your API and use the method [JSON.stringuify](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to the variable, so, the code passing the headers in my Fetch is:

```
saveAllResults(){
            let myvalue =JSON.stringify({"Step2":[{"selected":!1,"produto":"A70-5","ncm":"9506.62.00","aliqII":.2,"aliqIpi":0,"aliqPis":.021,"aliqCofins":.0965,"descricao":"BOLA DE BASQUETE","pesoUnitario":.43,"unitario":.78,"dumping":0,"cubagemUnitario":0,"quantidade":150,"icmEstadoDestino":0,"mvaAjustado":0,"markup":.12},{"selected":!1,"produto":"PINK-7-103","ncm":"7117.90.00","aliqII":.18,"aliqIpi":.12,"aliqPis":.021,"aliqCofins":.0965,"descricao":"BIJOUTERIAS EM METAL/ VIDRO ","pesoUnitario":.975,"unitario":1.52,"dumping":0,"cubagemUnitario":0,"quantidade":200,"icmEstadoDestino":0,"mvaAjustado":0,"markup":.11},{"selected":!1,"produto":"PINK-7-103","ncm":"7117.90.00","aliqII":.18,"aliqIpi":.12,"aliqPis":.021,"aliqCofins":.0965,"descricao":"BIJOUTERIAS EM METAL/ VIDRO ","pesoUnitario":.975,"unitario":1.52,"dumping":0,"cubagemUnitario":0,"quantidade":300,"icmEstadoDestino":0,"mvaAjustado":0,"markup":.19}],});
           
            fetch('http://localhost:4242/api/v1/dis', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                body: myvalue
            }).then(function(response){
                return response.json(myvalue);
            }).then(function(text){
                console.log(text);
            }).catch(function (error){
                console.error(error);
            })
            
}
```